# Performance Counter for DRAM Per-Rank Memory Access

Tags: performancecounter, perf, energy, memory-access, intel-pmu

I have an `Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4720HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz` (`Haswell`) processor. I need to retrieve the **number** of accesses to each DRAM **rank**, over time, to **estimate** its power consumption. Based on page `261` of the chipset documentation (i.e., [Datasheet, volume 2 (M- and H-processor lines)](https://cdrdv2.intel.com/v1/dl/getcontent/328902)), I could use the 32-bit value in register, `RAM—DRAM_ENERGY_STATUS`, as a DRAM energy **estimation**. But I need **rank-level** energy estimates. I could also use **core** and **offcore** DRAM access performance counters to **estimate** power consumption, but, as mentioned before, I need **per-rank statistics**. **Besides that**, they report **whole-system** stats, while energy is **calculated per-rank**. They also do **not** report many DRAM accesses.

Therefore, `IMC` counters (which are **uncore** counters) should be the **ideal** choice. `Perf` does **not** support **per-rank** counters. I tried to use [`PCM-Memory`](https://github.com/opcm/pcm/blob/master/pcm-memory.cpp) to access `IMC` counter information. But `/sys/bus/event_source/devices/uncore_imc` is **not** mounted by the kernel (the version is `5.0.0-37-generic`) and the tool does **not** detect the CPU. I tried to access **uncore** performance counters, **manually**. **Whole-system** DRAM access counters are documented, [here](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/monitoring-integrated-memory-controller-requests-in-the-2nd-3rd-and-4th-generation-intel.html) (They were **not** documented in the **above-mentioned** chipset manual). I can retrieve **total** DRAM **read** and **write** accesses using these counters. But, there is **no** information about **channel** or **rank-level** access stats. How can I find the **offset** associated with these **counters**? Should I use **trial and error**?

---

P.S.: This question is also asked at [Intel Software Tuning, Performance Optimization & Platform Monitoring Forum](https://community.intel.com/t5/Software-Tuning-Performance/Performance-Counter-for-DRAM-Per-Rank-Memory-Access/m-p/1263575).

Comment: Note that simultaneous cross-posting ([https://community.intel.com/t5/Software-Tuning-Performance/Performance-Counter-for-DRAM-Per-Rank-Memory-Access/m-p/1263575](https://community.intel.com/t5/Software-Tuning-Performance/Performance-Counter-for-DRAM-Per-Rank-Memory-Access/m-p/1263575)) is not cool, especially without linking them together, because it may result in wasted effort from multiple people.

Comment: @HadiBrais, But asking in multiple forums will increase the probability of an answer. Because not all members of a forum will be a member in the other one. What is the alternative solution?

Comment: Right, but it shouldn't happen that different people making effort to basically post the same answer for the same question. You can post the question on one forum, wait for a couple of days, and if no one provided a good answer, then post it somewhere else. It's also a good practice to link the questions to each other so that people from any forum can see all activity on the same question.

Comment: @HadiBrais, I added a link in both forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MSR_DRAM_ENERGY_STATUS` always reports an estimate of the energy consume by all memory channels. There is no easy way to break it into per-rank energy. This register reports a highly accurate estimate on Haswell.

The `5.0.0-37-generic` kernel is an Ubuntu kernel and does support the `uncore_imc/data_reads/` and `uncore_imc/data_writes/` events on Haswell, which represent a data read CAS command and a data write CAS command from the IMC, respectively. A full cache-line read and a full cache-line write transactions cause a single bursty 64-byte transaction on the memory bus to a single rank. A partial read is also executed as a single full-line read on the bus, but a partial write may require a full line read followed by a full line write due to restrictions in the protocol. Partial writes are generally negligible.

The `uncore_imc/data_reads/` and `uncore_imc/data_writes/` events occur for requests targeting DRAM memory generated by any unit, not just cores. These names are given by `perf` and they correspond to `UNC_IMC_DRAM_DATA_READS` and `UNC_IMC_DRAM_DATA_WRITES`, respectively, which are mentioned in the Intel article you've cited. The other three events mentioned there allow you count requests (not CAS commands!) for each of the three possible sources separately (GT, IA, and IO). You won't find them  listed under `/sys/bus/event_source/devices/uncore_imc/events` on your old kernel. They are supported in `perf` starting with mainstream kernel v5.9-rc2.

By the way, `PCM` does support these events as well, which it uses to report read and write bandwdith over all channels, but you should use the tool `pcm.x`, not `pcm-memory.x`, which only works on server processors.

A Haswell H-processor line processor has a single on-die memory controller with two DDR3L 64-bit channels. Each channel can contain zero, one, or two DIMMs with a total capacity of up to 32 GBs over all channels. Moreover, each DIMM can contain up to two ranks, so a single channel can contain anywhere between zero and four ranks. The i7-4720HQ is a high-end mobile processor. You're probably on a laptop with 8 GBs or 16 GBs of memory. If the memory topology was not changed since purchase, it probably has only two 4GB or 8GB DIMMs, one in each channel, with one remaining free slot per channel available for expansion if desired by the user. This means that there are either one or two ranks per channel.

You can approximate the number of accesses to each rank given the knowledge of how physical addresses are mapped to ranks. If each channel is populated with a single rank DIMM of the same capacity, the mapping is simple on your processor. Bit 6 of the physical address (i.e., the seventh bit) determines which channel, and therefore which rank, a request is mapped to. You can collect a set of samples of physical addresses of requests at the IMC by running `perf record` on `MEM_LOAD_UOPS_L3_MISS_RETIRED.LOCAL_DRAM` with the `--phys-data` option. Obviously this set of samples may only be representative of core-originated retired loads that reach the IMC, which are a small subset of all requests at the IMC.

It appears to me that you want to measure the number of memory accesses per rank in order to estimate the the per-rank energy from the total DRAM energy, but this is not trivial at all for the following reasons:

- Not all CAS commands are of the same energy cost. Precharge and activate commands are not counted by any event and may consume significant energy, especially with high row buffer miss rates.
- Even if there are zero requests in the IMC, as long as there is at least one active core, the memory channels are powered and do consume energy.
- The amount of time it takes to process a request of the same type and to the same address may vary depending surrounding requests due to timing delays required by rank-to-rank turnarounds and read-write switching.

Despite of all of that, I imagine it may be possible to build a good model of upper and lower bounds on per-rank energy given a representative estimate of the number of requests to each rank (as discussed above).

The bottom line is that there is no easy way to get the luxury of per-rank counting like on server processors.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! How can I **confirm** that rank access stats are **not** reported at some offset in the `32 KB` space starting at `MCHBAR`? These stats do **not** appear to be that complicated to store!

Comment: The above-mentioned `events` are **not** supported in my kernel. What you suggest about `phys-data` is reasonable. Is it reliable **enough** considering the fact that **some dispatched** micro-operations and also **all write accesses** are omitted?

Comment: My Laptop has an `8 GB` (**dual** rank) and a `4 GB` (**single** rank) DIMM, each on a **different** channel. I **don't** think that the datasheet **matches** the motherboard. I think that each channel has only **one** slot and, therefore, supports at **most 1** DIMM. The **first** `8 GB` of physical address is **interleaved** (with the **granularity** of, probably, `64` bytes) btwn the **2** channels and the range `[8GB-12GB[` is mapped to the **larger** DIMM. Ultimately, I will have to **remove** the smaller DIMM to arrive at a **simpler** mapping that **can** be **reverse-engineered**.

Comment: "Is it reliable enough..." Depends on the workloads you're working with. You have to show or argue that the sampled load addresses provide a representative rank-wise distribution of all requests at the IMC. This is easy for simple benchmarks, but you may have to use a simulator for real benchmarks.

Comment: I checked the `32 Bit` values (i.e., at offsets `0`, `4`,...) in the whole `32 KB` range for `MCHBAR`. None of them seemed related. Most of them were **zero**. Some where **constant** and the others did **not** match the *whole system* counters.